# What is "+[ ]" means in [a+[ ] for a in S]?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

What is `+[ ]` means in `[a+[ ] for a in S]`

```
nums=[1,2,3]
S=[[]]
for i in nums:
    S+=[a+[i] for a in S]
```

I know this code achieves all the subsets for nums

```
[[],[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]
```

But what is `+ []` means in the code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given that:

- `a` is a list.
- `[i]` is a list.

Therefore:

- `a + [i]` means that we concatenate the two lists together.

For example:

- `[1, 2, 3, 4] + [5] == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`